# Can you send HTTP Response from another Server?

Tags: node.js, http, laravel-5, server, response

Silly question perhaps.

I've been playing with Node.js lately, and like how easy it is to set up servers and make requests etc. I haven't tried yet, but was wondering how I might forward data from one request to another server, and have that second server send response to the client.

Is this possible?

i.e.

CLIENTX -> SERVER A -> SERVER B -> CLIENT X

Whats confusing to me is how to send to same client? This information should be present in the request header though no? Is it a matter of forwarding that information to SERVER B?

I am in a situation where I am accepting requests on a Node.js server, and would like to forward some of the data to a Laravel API I have created and send response to client form there.

Appreciate your answers,

Matt

Comment: HTTP responses are, well, *responses* and they can only be sent as a reaction to a client request. A client won;t honor a totally-unsolicited "response" from a server coming out of nowhere. Are you imagining that Client X sends requests to both Server A and Server B at roughly the same time? Or that Client X sends a request to Server B much later?

Comment: Or would it be okay to just have Server A make the API call to Server B and return the result to Client X? (i.e., Client X has no need to know Server B exists)

Comment: Do you want server B to spoof its IP & masquerade as ServerA and respond to the request made to Server A? I'd like to know the answer to that too :) Good question! I have been thinking of this for years, but did not investigate.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty easy to do with the [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) module.

Here's an example implementation for "Server A", that would pass all requests to Server B as-is, and send back its responses to the client:

```
'use strict';
const http    = require('http');
const request = require('request').defaults({ followRedirect : false, encoding : null });

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  let endpoint = 'http://server-b.example.com' + req.url;
  req.pipe(request(endpoint)).pipe(res);
}).listen(3000);
```

Instead of `request` you could also implement this with the [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) module, but `request` makes it easier.

Any requests to `http://server-a.example.com/some/path/here` will be passed to Server B, with the same path (+ method, query strings, body data, etc).

`followRedirect` and `encoding` are two options that I found useful when passing requests to other servers like this. They are documented [here](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback).

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, it doesn't work like that. **Server B** can't send a response back to **Client X**, because that would come as a response to NO REQUEST. **Client X** never asked **Server B** for anything.

[image: meme]

Here's how this works:

1. **Client X** makes a request to **Server A**
2. In the context of that request, **Server A** makes a request to **Server B** (Your Laravel API)
3. **Server A** makes a note of the response received from **Server B**
4. **Server A** then sends the response back to **Client X**

Sample implementation:

```
var http = require('http');

function onRequest(request, response) {
    var options = {
        host: 'stackoverflow.com',
        port: 80,
        path: '/'
    };

    var body = '';

    http.get(options, function(responseFromRemoteApi) {
        responseFromRemoteApi.on('data', function(chunk) {
            // When this event fires we append chunks of 
            // response to a variable
            body += chunk;
        });
        responseFromRemoteApi.on('end', function() {
            // We have the complete response from Server B (stackoverflow.com)
            // Send that as response to client
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/html' });
            response.write(body);
            response.end();
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Error when calling remote API: ' + e.message);
    });
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('Listening for requests on port ' + (process.env.PORT || 3000));
```

Comment: That makes server A a proxy. Can server B respond to client masquerading as server A (spoofing IP and all)?